# Transparent header in beamer

Tags: beamer

How can I make the frame header in the beamer transparent? The use case would be when you have a super tall image that surpasses the height of the frame minus the height of the header (and for whatever reason you rather not shrink the image).

To be clear, I want the blue area on the top to be a bit (but not fully) transparent.
(Picture adapted from the answer to [another (unrelated) question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79307/how-can-i-superimpose-tikzpicture-on-a-certain-part-of-the-page/79309#79309).)

[image]

Comment: You should add a minimal working example that contains the theme you use etc. Apart from that, wouldn't the image cover the title bar anyways?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beamer - How to set frametitle box translucent so that backeground image can be seen blurred](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270082/beamer-how-to-set-frametitle-box-translucent-so-that-backeground-image-can-be)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try a big image via TikZ and `remember picture` ?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title Text}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[fill=white,fill opacity=0.5,text opacity=1,inner sep=0] at (current page.center)
  {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight,width=8cm]{ctanlion}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]